# org.postgres.Driver Class Exception - Beginner

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, connection

thanks for any help, I am a complete noob here but trying to learn.
the below code is simply trying to create a connection to a database. I am getting this error back:

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgres.Driver
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>     at CreateDB.main(CreateDB.java:11)
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgres.Driver
> ```

having researched online the solution i come across is to check the library is added to to build path. i can confirm that i have (I think). to do this i right clicked the prject -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> external JARS and navigated to the postgresql - 42.41.4..jar which is located in "...\eclipse-workspace\libraries\"
I can see that the library is added under referenced libraries within the project.
not a clue now im stuck. any help is genuinely appreciated.

I am learning from here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class CreateDB {
    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgres.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.postgresql://localhost:1080/VEM", "postgres", "Diablo12" ); //creates connection with U&P
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() +": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Database opened successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the wrong class name (see Henry's answer): the `Class.forName()` is no longer needed since Java 6

Answer (score 1):

The correct driver name is: `org.postgresql.Driver`. So your code should look like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class CreateDB {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.postgresql://localhost:1080/VEM", "postgres", "Diablo12" ); //creates connection with U&P
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() +": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Database opened successfully");
   }
}
```

The false driver name causes java to throw the `ClassNotFoundException` because the class with the passed name could not be found in the classpath.
Since Java 6 the loading of the driver via `Class.forName()` is not needed any more, like [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) pointed out in his comment.

Comment: Or simply leave out the `Class.forName()` this is not needed any more

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's true. I explained it because it was the reason of the failure.